# Return joined tables in JSON format with SQLAlchemy and Flask jsonify

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building an endpoint in python that will return my catalog with all items within each category. I would like to join two tables (**Catalog and Items**) in my database based on a foreign key constraint and output this in a JSON format.

**Currently I have tried**

```
@app.route('/catalog/JSON/')
@login_required
  def getCatalog():
  categories = session.query(Category).join(Item).all()
  return jsonify(Catalog=[r.serializable for r in categories])
```

However, this only returns item data and data about the catalog such a name.

**My Current Models**

```
class Category(Base):
__tablename__ = 'category'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(32), nullable=False)

@property
def serializable(self):
    return {'id': self.id, 'username': self.username}

class Item(Base):
__tablename__ = 'item'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
description = Column(String(255))
user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
user = relationship(User)
category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
category = relationship(Category)

@property
def serializable(self):
    return {
        'id': self.id,
        'name': self.name,
        'description': self.description,
        'category_id': self.category_id,
        'user_id': self.user_id
    }
```

I am new to flask so I'm not 100% sure if what I am trying to accomplish is something already resolved by the framework or by sqlalchemy.

Comment: `for r in catalog` - do you mean `categories`?

Comment: Your `serializable` properties don't return the related objects, so there's no way for the relationship to appear in your result. Maybe include `self.category` in `Item.serializable` and iterate of items in your query.

Comment: yes i mean categories

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Are you not going to try what I said in the other comment?

Comment: How do I include self.category within the item serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring `category = relationship(Category)` in `Item`, instances of `Item` have a `category` attribute that corresponds to the correct row in the database. In the background, this will fetch the row from the database if necessary. You should be careful about this when handling collections of items as it may result in calling the database once for each item - this is called the n+1 problem.

So to answer the question "How do I include self.category within the item serializable?", you can literally just write:

```
class Item(Base):
    ...

    @property
    def serializable(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            ...
            'category': self.category.serializable
        }
```

But this is probably not a good idea as you might accidentally cause an extra database call when writing `item.serializable`.

In any case we really want to list all the items in a category, so we need to use the foreign key relationship in the other direction. This is done by adding the `backref` argument to the relationship:

```
category = relationship(Category, backref='items')
```

and now `Category` instances will have an `items` attribute. Then here is how to write `getCatalog`:

```
def getCatalog():
    categories = Session().query(Category).options(joinedload(Category.items)).all()
    return dict(Catalog=[dict(c.serializable, items=[i.serializable
                                                     for i in c.items])
                         for c in categories])
```

Here `.options(joinedload(Category.items))` performs a SQL JOIN to fetch the items in advance so that `c.items` doesn't cause extra database queries. (Thanks Ilja)

Here is the full code for a complete demo:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, joinedload

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32), nullable=False)

    @property
    def serializable(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'name': self.name}


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = relationship(Category, backref='items')

    @property
    def serializable(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'name': self.name}


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

category1 = Category(id=1, name='fruit')
category2 = Category(id=2, name='clothes')
session = Session()
session.add_all([category1, category2,
                 Item(id=1, name='apple', category=category1),
                 Item(id=2, name='orange', category=category1),
                 Item(id=3, name='shirt', category=category2),
                 Item(id=4, name='pants', category=category2)])
session.commit()


def getCatalog():
    categories = Session().query(Category).options(joinedload(Category.items)).all()
    return dict(Catalog=[dict(c.serializable, items=[i.serializable
                                                     for i in c.items])
                         for c in categories])


from pprint import pprint

pprint(getCatalog())
```

The echoed SQL shows that only one SELECT is sent to the database. The actual output is:

```
{'Catalog': [{'id': 1,
              'items': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'apple'},
                        {'id': 2, 'name': 'orange'}],
              'name': 'fruit'},
             {'id': 2,
              'items': [{'id': 3, 'name': 'shirt'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'pants'}],
              'name': 'clothes'}]}
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks, I did not know that and that was well spotted. Using fresh sessions confirms that you're right, and I realise now I didn't even commit my session. I've updated.